# How to find index of colliding Game Object in OnCollisionEnter2D()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a prefab and instantiated it a number of times in a script that it attached to another game object as below.

```
void Start () {

    badGuys= new List<GameObject> ();

    int numberOfBadGuys = 6;
    Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera> ();

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfBadGuys + 1; i++) {
        GameObject badGuyObject =  (GameObject)Instantiate(badGuy, new Vector3(Screen.width*i/2, Screen.height*i/6, camera.nearClipPlane ), Quaternion.identity );
        badGuys.Add(badGuyObject);
    }

}
```

Since all of the instantiated objects in the array have the same tag and game object, how can I find the index of the colliding object in the array?

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {
    Debug.Log("collision has began");

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "badGuy") {
             // how can I tell the index of colliding game object in badGuys array
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you detecting the collision in the same script that contains the array of badguys?

Comment: Yes, they both in the same script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just loop and compare the GameObject like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("collision has began");

    int collidedBadGuyIndex = -1; //This variable should be outside this function.

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "badGuy")
    {
        for (int i=0; i<badGuys.Length; i++)
        {
            if (col.gameObject.Equals(badGuys[i]))
            {
                collidedBadGuyIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work then you could add a script to the badguys (i.e. BadGuyScript.cs) and inside of the script add a variable called `bool hasCollided = false;` then when the badguy collides set the variable to `true` and then loop all the badguys and find the index of the badguy that has the value equal to `true`.

Comment: hi Agustin.  it's true that on the face of it as the problem is described, the only way to find the index is to loop as you say.  But as "yes" mentions below, each of the items should be aware of its own index.

Comment: @Joe Blow Yeah I know his solution is better, is just that we posted almost at the same time, so he probably poster while I was writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making your bad guys aware of their index?

Comment: indeed.  and moreover, nullitious, don't forget that you can also detect the collision ***on the bad guy***.  you should do that and do any processing in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one **parent** for all your bad guys.