# how to create an enum for a prefab to be instantiated with an image for sprite

Tags: enums, unity-game-engine

Basically I’ve created a prefab, “badGuy” of which there are three types. Each has it’s their own sprite images. So I created the following enum in a script attached to my badGuy prefab:

```
public enum BadGuyType {
  green,
  blue,
  red
}
```

All along I have been using one image for my prefab since I didn’t have a enum. The badGuy game object had a public property for  me to add it through the inspector and instantiate it a number of times as below:

```
public GameObject badGuy; //I set this in the inspector
void Start () {

badGuys= new List<GameObject> ();

int numberOfBadGuys = 6;
Camera camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera> ();

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfBadGuys + 1; i++) {
    GameObject badGuyObject =  (GameObject)Instantiate(badGuy, new Vector3(Screen.width*i/2, Screen.height*i/6, camera.nearClipPlane ), Quaternion.identity );
    badGuys.Add(badGuyObject);
}
```

How can I set images (preferably programmatically) for my BadGuyType enum and select them when instantiating my badGuy game objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each badGuy to have its own properties then you need to create a general class for badguys and put all the variables inside it. Create a Script called BadGuysManager then implement all your bad guy's actions inside there or copy the one from below.

Function signatures:

```
void createBadGuy(GameObject badGuyPrefab, BadGuyType badGuyType, Vector3 badGuyPosition)
void setBadGuyType(BadGuyType badGuyType)
BadGuyType getBadGuyType()
void killBadGuy()
GameObject getBadGuyGameObject()
```

In your `test.cs` script, you can add the BadGuysManager script with a list.

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Attch the gameObject bad guy here
    public GameObject badGuyPrefab;

    List<BadGuysManager> badGuys = new List<BadGuysManager>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        /////////////////////////////////////CREATE 3 bad guys with different colors

        //Bad Guy 1, Green Color
        badGuys.Add(gameObject.AddComponent<BadGuysManager>());
        badGuys[0].createBadGuy(badGuyPrefab, BadGuyType.green, Vector3.zero);

        //Bad Guy 2, Blue Color
        badGuys.Add(gameObject.AddComponent<BadGuysManager>());
        badGuys[1].createBadGuy(badGuyPrefab, BadGuyType.blue, Vector3.zero);

        //Bad Guy 3, Red Color
        badGuys.Add(gameObject.AddComponent<BadGuysManager>());
        badGuys[2].createBadGuy(badGuyPrefab, BadGuyType.red, Vector3.zero);

        /////////////////////////////////////CHANGE bad guy type later on
        //badGuys[0].setBadGuyType(BadGuyType.green);

        /////////////////////////////////////READ bad guy type 
        //BadGuyType badGuyType = badGuys[0].getBadGuyType();

        /////////////////////////////////////Get bad guy 
        //GameObject badGuy = badGuys[0].getBadGuyGameObject();

        /////////////////////////////////////KILL bad guy type 
        //badGuys[0].killBadGuy();

    }
}
```

The code below should be in your `BadGuysManager`.cs script. This should get you started. You can easily extend or add more functions to the `BadGuysManager` class.

```
public class BadGuysManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject badGuy; //I set this in the inspector
    private BadGuyType playerGuyType = BadGuyType.NONE;

    public void setBadGuyType(BadGuyType badGuyType)
    {
        playerGuyType = badGuyType;

        if (badGuy == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to set color because Bad Guy Prefab is null! Call createBadGuy function first");
            return; //exit
        }
        if (badGuyType == BadGuyType.green)
        {
            badGuy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        else if (badGuyType == BadGuyType.blue)
        {

            badGuy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
        }
        if (badGuyType == BadGuyType.red)
        {

            badGuy.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }
    }

    public BadGuyType getBadGuyType()
    {
        return playerGuyType;
    }


    public void createBadGuy(GameObject badGuyPrefab, BadGuyType badGuyType, Vector3 badGuyPosition)
    {
        if (badGuyPrefab == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Bad Guy Prefab is null!");
            return; //exit
        }

        badGuy = (GameObject)Instantiate(badGuyPrefab, badGuyPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        setBadGuyType(badGuyType);
    }

    public void killBadGuy()
    {
        Destroy(badGuy);
        Destroy(this);
    }

    public GameObject getBadGuyGameObject()
    {
        return badGuy;
    }
}

public enum BadGuyType
{
    NONE,
    green,
    blue,
    red
}
```

Comment: So if my `BadGuysManager` script is attached to my BadGuy prefab then I can replace `badGuy` with `gameObject`

Comment: No no no. That's no how the BadGuyManager works. You don't attach your BadGuysManager script anywhere in the scene. You use gameObject.AddComponent<BadGuysManager>() to make a new one. Then use createBadGuy to initialize the new badGuy in BadGuysManager  by passing in prefab to it.badGuy  is initialized when  createBadGuy  is called. Please look at the `test.cs` script. It shows you how to use it.

Comment: nullitiousness, dont try to enforce your style onto unity, go with the flow, adapt to how they intend to use it. its "component driven" so make use of components and dont try to have a single master class controll everything. while its not completely impossible, its the overly complicated way of doing things and you only waste time to find ways to work around unitys paradigm.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks a lot. I was using the accepted solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690789/how-to-find-index-of-colliding-game-object-in-oncollisionenter2d to loop through to get collision index of the list. Now that it's of type `BadGuyManager` I changed the condition `if (col.gameObject.Equals(badGuys[i]))` to `if (col.gameObject.Equals(badGuys[i].gameObject))` but it never gets satisfied though collision happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: why dont you just have an integer on your bad guys which tracks their index in the list? this way you dont need to iterate over all baddies, but you instantly know which one it is (which also might become useful for selection and stuff). you only need to keep the indexes in line if you plan to remove them again (=just lower each consequent index after the removed object by 1)

Comment: Dude that is so easy to implement. I edited my answer and added `getBadGuyGameObject()` function to the `BadGuyManager` class. It returns the `badguy` in `BadGuyManager`. So now, you can do `(col.gameObject.Equals(badGuys[i].getBadGuyGameObject()))`. That should work. Please create new question with your whole code if you still have more questions.

Comment: do exactly what YES says in yes's first comment above.

Comment: also do exactly what Programmer says specifically.

Comment: @Programmer thanks but actually `(col.gameObject.Equals(badGuys[i].getBadGuyGameObject()))`didn't work, I am not too sure why. I rather created a `getBadGuyPosition() ` function that returned the position and compared positions.

Comment: @Programmer I've been following Nullititiousness question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730454/colliding-objects-bouncing-off-when-istrigger-is-true-instead-of-passing-through?lq=1, which led me here. I tried your code and realized that whenever I tried to change the image Eg, `badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/testPic2") as Sprite;` and regardless of the index, it only changed the image of first element in the list. Also, when I checked the positions, I got the same position for every element....

Comment: @Programmer ....`getBadGuyGameObject()` might not be working as you expect it. I'm not sure what's causing this but I recommend you take another look at

Comment: @Jickery I will take a look.

Comment: @Nullititiousness I apologize. This is was my fault. I forgot to comment `badGuy = badGuyPrefab;` in `createBadGuy` function. I used that line to test something but forgot to remove it. I also took this time to fix the  `killBadGuy` function. This answer is updated. Just copy the new class from this answer and replace it with your old one. You can look in the paste bin link below to see what the old code looks like compared to the new one. http://pastebin.com/7ykciKZ0

Comment: You can go here and accept Joe's answer as it has other important stuff for you and also updated answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730454/colliding-objects-bouncing-off-when-istrigger-is-true-instead-of-passing-through

Comment: @Jickery You are right. There was a problem but it is now fixed.