# Colliding objects bouncing off when isTrigger is true instead of passing through

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have looped through some game objects to set the `isTrigger` property before a certain collision occurs but though the property is true collision with the object still occurs. Please see the relevant code below:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "object1") {
         for (int i = 0; i < badGuys.Count; i++)    {
         badGuys[i].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().isTrigger = true;
      }

      }

    else if (col.gameObject.tag == "object2") {

       // collision with object1 always occurs before object2, though isTrigger is true the colliding object doesn't pass through the badGuys game objects, it bounces off on collision
      }
   else if (col.gameObject.tag == "object3") {
      for (int i = 0; i < badGuys.Count; i++)   {
         badGuys[i].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().isTrigger = false;
      }
      }
    else if (col.gameObject.tag == "badGuy") {

      }

}
```

collision with object1 always occurs before object2, though isTrigger is true the colliding object doesn't pass through the badGuys game objects, it bounces off on collision. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE 1**

I just realized that the `isTrigger` value is true or false in the inspector depending on the time I stop the game. For example if I stop the game after Object1 collision the `isTrigger`  is true and when I stop the game after collision with object3 it false. This inconsistency makes debugging very cumbersome. Is this a bug or something?

**UPDATE 2**

Based on recommendation from Joe Blow and Agustin0987 I used the `enabled` property of `Collider2D` instead of `isTrigger`. I also removed virtually all the code in `OnCollisionEnter2D` to get a simple test scenario. Please see code below:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "object1") {

        if (badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false) {
            badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;
            Debug.Log ("CHANGED TO TRUE");
            Debug.Log ("bad guy  collider enabled is " + badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled);

        }


        else if (badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true) {
            badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
            Debug.Log ("CHANGED TO FALSE");
            Debug.Log ("bad guy collider enabled is " + badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject().GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled);


        }
    }
    else if (col.gameObject.tag == "badGuy") {
       Debug.Log("collided with bad guy"); // DOESN'T OCCUR
    }

}
```

Instead of looping through this time, I decided to test for one. The `else if` is where `enabled` is `true` always satisfied though the `Log` prints `false`  and the `if` where `enabled` is `false` is never satisfied. In the inspector, the Box Collider2D for bad guys is always unchecked. Collision with the badGuy never occurs. Based on my simple scenario code I thought it should be working.

Comment: What is the amount of badGuys.Count? Also what do you mean by change by time?

Comment: i cannot comprehend why you would be trying to set isTrigger.  can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: please dont take it as offense, but i think you should do some tutorials on how to use unity before you attempt to craete something on your own.
it doesnt have to be tutorials for each and every aspect of the engine, but if you need colliders and triggers you should at least watch/read the tutorials provided on the unity webpages.

Comment: @Programmer Sorry for not replying early. The count reaches a max of 12. When I set `isTrigger` to true during object1’s collision and log the change it is true. But during object2’s collision though at this point `isTrigger` is true, the other colliding object doesn’t pass through `badguys` game objects. I also tried testing with a list containing only 1 object but it still didn’t work. I just update the question.

Comment: @JoeBlow Sorry for not replying early. Based on my gameplay object1’s collision always occurs before object2’s. During object2’s collision I wouldn’t want collision with `badguys` to take place. That’s why I change the `isTrigger` to true. I just update the question.

Comment: @yes Thanks for you suggestion, I've already read the unity documentation and a few other tutorials but I've not found anything similar to my issue. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never, ever ever

## I mean absolutely *never*

use "else if".

Simply, never, ever - ever - type "else if" for the rest of your life, until you die.

In the first instance, delete all your code and replace it with this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
Debug.Log("We will deal with this ......... " +col.gameObject.name);
if (col.gameObject.tag == "object1")
    {
    Debug.Log("\t handling 'object' type issue");
    HandleObjectIssue(col)
    return; //NOTE HERE
    }
if (col.gameObject.tag == "object1")
    {
    Debug.Log("\t handling 'bad guy' type issue");
    HandleBadGuyIssue(col)
    return; //NOTE HERE
    }
}

private void HandleObjectIssue(Collision2D col)
{
Debug.Log("'\t\t object', I'm dealing with this .. " +col.gameObject.name);
}


private void HandleBadGuyIssue(Collision2D col)
{
Debug.Log("\t\t 'badguy', I'm dealing with this .. " +col.gameObject.name);
}
```

Run that extensively and "unit test" it.  If you like, convert back (USING THAT CODE) to a "loop" method to look at all items.  In any event, test that extensively.

--

Secondly, add this routine ..

```
private void ToggleColliderOnGameObject( GameObject gg )
{
Debug.Log("I'm supposed to toggle the collider on: " +gg.name);
Collider2D { or whatever } col = gg.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
bool currentState = GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled;

Debug.Log("\t it is currently: " +currentState);

bool newState = ! currentState;
col.enabled = newState;

Debug.Log("\t\t but now it is: " +newState);
}
```

... and start unit testing with it.  So you will have code like:

```
 ToggleColliderOnGameObject( badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject() );
```

For example, try some things like this:

```
void Start()
    {
    InvokeRepeating("teste", 1f, 1f);
    }
private void Teste()
    {
    ToggleColliderOnGameObject( badGuys[4].getBadGuyGameObject() );
    }
```

After experimenting with that for some time and unit testing, you will be able to move on.

Note that apart from other problems, it is likely that (for example) your routine "getBadGuyGameObject" is returning the wrong thing - or some similar problem.

**EDIT**:

**Remove** `badGuy = badGuyPrefab;` from your `public void createBadGuy(GameObject badGuyPrefab, BadGuyType badGuyType, Vector3 badGuyPosition)` function. This was a mistake in Programmer's code from the link in your comment.

Comment: I've started unit testing. If you would like to see what's in my `badGuy` code please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702497/how-to-create-an-enum-for-a-prefab-to-be-instantiated-with-an-image-for-sprite. I am also suspecting `getBadGuyGameObject`

Comment: @Joe Blow I found the problem. I modified your answer with the solution. It was my fault. I used that for testing and forgot to remove or comment it out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to enable/detect the collision between `badGuys` and `object2` only if `object1` collides with whatever object has this script attached (seems to be some kind of BadGuyManager). So I would recommend that instead of setting `isTrigger` to true or false, you should try to enable or disable the whole `Collider2D.

P.S: I agree with Joe Blow in that you should explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @JoeBlow thanks, well noted. I just updated the question - UPDATE 2